# How to populate a dropdown list using HashTable? or HashMap?

Tags: dictionary, foreach, hashmap, jstl, hashtable

In Java Bean Page I write this code:-

```
package sandip;

import java.sql;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import sandip.DataBaseConnection;

public class UserBean {

  private ArrayList<Assay> assays = new ArrayList<Assay>();
  private ArrayList<String> StringValue = new ArrayList<String>();

  private Map<String, String> details = new HashMap<String, String>();

public void setDetails() {    

    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    String sql = null;
    DataBaseConnection obj = new DataBaseConnection();
    Connection conn = null;
    conn = obj.connectToDb();


    try{

      stmt = conn.createStatement();
      sql = "SELECT `email`, `password` FROM `accounts` LIMIT 0, 12";
      rs =  stmt.executeQuery(sql);

      while(rs.next()) {
        details.put(rs.getString("password"), rs.getString("email"));
      }
    }catch(SQLException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }catch(Exception ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }

  }

  public Map<String, String> getDetails() {

    return this.details;
  }
}
```

and in my jsp page I have used as to Iterate through loop:-

But it does not print anything.What Should I change now?If I have to do anything else?

```
<h3>Hashtable iteration</h3>
<table border="1">
  <c:forEach items="${userDetails.details}" var="item">
    <tr>
      <td align="center"><c:out value="${item.name}"/></td>
      <td align="center">${item.value}</td>
    </tr>
  </c:forEach>
    <br>
  <ol>
    <c:forEach items="${userDetails.details}" var="item">
      <li><c:out value="${item.key}"/>=<c:out value="${item.value}"/></li>
      </c:forEach>
  </ol>
```

The ${item.key} does not print any value

Answer (score 0):

How are the userDetails set into JSP? Who is calling the setDetails method?

Anyway, it's not good idea to have setter method without any argument, because it violates the java bean convention. According to your `getDetails()` getter, your `setDetails()` should accept the `Map<String, String>` as a parameter. I would use the `UserBean` only as a data holder and move the database fetching code into servlet (or other controller, service or DAO object).